# Passing parameters for a Action in Acumatica Rest API WebService EndPoint

Tags: rest, acumatica, endpoint

My Requirement: In Bills and adjustment screen, I want to add subcontracts from the "ADD SUBCONTRACTS" button from gird button.

[image: These two records are subcontracts to be add to the bill document in detail]

I am using post Method in postman like this

Post :localhost/AcumaticaXMSI/entity/DefaultExtended/18.200.001/Bill/addSubcontracts
 with enitity and paramters

[image]

Then the result we get is, Only SC-000002 is inserted into detail.
I want two records to be inserted  in detail line and also specified record to be inserted from POSTMAN JSON format

[image]

I tried with this json syntax(below) but did not help to add specific subcontract record 
Please can anyone suggest me the correct JSON syntax for selecting all subcontracts and also specific subcontract to be passed through parameters in postman action

[image]

additional information
[image]

Comment: I am waiting for someone to answer my question. Please

Comment: Many people are currently in Christmas holydays.

Comment: Can you provide the customization and extended endpoint? Acumatica is not using Selected checkbox in case of adding multiple lines from REST API.

Comment: Add subcontract button is not a default acumatica functionality as well as DefaultExtended endpoint that you use. I don't think anyone can help you with the request without seeing the customization you use and the endpoint definition you use.

Comment: @DmitriiNaumov your comment from 2020 is no longer true (For Acumatica Construction Edition 22+) and this exact symptom still exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass parameter into action ( or button ) which triggers pop up directly. Reason why you can't do that, is that all pop ups are triggered as an exception. And from C# standpoint, each time when exception is triggered, passed values are lost. From Acumatica standpoint, any time, when exception is thrown, then it's kind of equal for clicking on the button cancel. Of course, if exception is pop up UI exception, Acumatica has mechanism of catching that, but in web api, another approach may be suggested.

As usually, I do this:

1. Add some text field, or text fields on the form.
2. For added fields, at the RowSelected event I hide these fields, based on condition:

   ```
   if(!Base.IsContractBasedAPI)
   {
       //Hide fields, so ordinary users will not see added fields on the ui
   }
   ```
3. Add one more synthetic button, which can be also hidden, using mentioned technique in the point two
4. Expose synthetic button as endpoint
5. Make two api calls,
   5.1. API call which sets value of the field
   5.2. Execute additional button

Additional button may have following logic:

```
public virtual IEnumerable yourAdditionalButton(PXAdapter adapter)
{
   try
   {
       //execute your button
   }
   catch(Exception ex ) // to do: replace with actual redirection exception
   {
       
   }
   //based on data, which you made in step 5 arrange execution of needed button. Just can't quickly allocate button Add Subcontract
   //Execute button one more time, this time exception shouldn't appear

}
```

I believe some other workarounds may exist, but general approach is like I described.